# How does re-playing finished quests work?

Tags: diablo-iii

If someone who has already beat certain questlines joins your game and you're behind them can they help you finish those quests? Is it still like Diablo 2 that the quests are based on the creator of the game? I feel like I had read that there will be a level limit so that people can't get rushed through the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can help you. And yes, each quest has a minimum and maximum level for joining to the game.

[image]